# If $f\in C^0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is subharmonic and $\limsup_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)\le 0$, then $f$ must be non-positive in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $f\in C^0(\mathbb{R}^)$ be *subharmonic*, i.e. for each closed ball $\overline{B}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ it holds: $$u\in C^2(B)\text{ is harmonic in }B\text{ and }f\le u\text{ on }\partial B\;\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;\;f\le u\text{ in }B\tag{1}$$

Now, suppose that $$\limsup_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)\le 0\tag{2}$$ I want to conclude, that we must have $$f\le 0\;\;\;\text{in }\mathbb{R}^n\tag{3}$$ Unfortunately, I've no idea how I need to use the subharmonicity here. I've read that one should consider a sequence $\left\{x_m\right\}$ with $$f(x_m)\stackrel{m\to\infty}{\to}\sup_{\mathbb{R}^n}f\tag{4}$$ However, I don't understand how this helps to prove $(3)$ (and why such a sequence needs to exist, in the first place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuous subharmonic functions satisfy the following maximum principle(s): If a continuous subharmonic function has a global maximum in a domain (open connected set), then it is constant. If a continuous subharmonic function has a local maximum at $p$, then it is constant on a neighbourhood of $p$

Assume $f$ were not non-positive, i.e. there is an $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $f(x_0) > 0$. Since

$$\limsup_{\lvert x\rvert\to\infty} f(x) \leqslant 0,$$

it follows that there is a compact $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x) \leqslant \frac{1}{2} f(x_0)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus K$.

$f$ attains its (global) maximum on $K$. Contradiction.

Comment: I don't get it: Why must $K$ exist?

Comment: Because of the $\limsup$ condition. If there were an unbounded set where $f(x) \geqslant \frac{1}{2} f(x_0)$, then we'd have a sequence $x_m$ with $\lvert x_m\rvert \to \infty$ and $f(x_m) \geqslant \frac{1}{2} f(x_0)$, so $\limsup\limits_{m\to\infty} f(x_m) > 0$.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand it. We assume that an unbounded set $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ with $$f(x)\ge\frac 12 f(x_0)>0\tag{5}$$ exists. Since $U$ is unbounded, we can choose a sequence $\left\{x_m\right\}\subseteq U$ with $|x_m|\stackrel{m\to\infty}{\to}\infty$ and, obviously, $$\limsup_{m\to\infty}f(x_m)\ge\frac 12 f(x_0)>0$$ So, $(5)$ is untrue and no such $U$ can exist.

Comment: However, in terms of propositional logic, the statement "There is a compact $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ with $$f(x)\le\frac 12f(x_0)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus K\text{"}\tag{6}$$ is not the negation of "There is no such $U$". So, I've got still some lack of understanding (Please be patient ;)

Comment: "There is no unbounded set $U$ with $f(x) \geqslant c$ for all $x\in U$" means that in particular the set $V = f^{-1}([c,+\infty))$ is not unbounded. That is, $V$ is bounded. But $V$ is closed [if we didn't have the continuity of $f$, it would still follow that $\overline{V}$ is bounded from the boundedness of $V$], hence compact. Thus take $K = V$ ($K = \overline{V}$).

Comment: Now, that's clear to me. You've shown that $x_0\in K$ and $$f(x)<f(x_0)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus K\;.$$ Hence, $f$ attains its maximum in $K$. However, $K$ is not necessarily a domain. Clearly, we can choose $r>0$ such that the open ball $\Omega:=B_r(x_0)$ is contained in $K$ and voilà, we have found a bounded domain $\Omega$, so that $v$ attains its maximum in it. But what *exactly* can we conclude by the maximum principle? Of course, we now know that $f$ is constant in $\Omega$. More precisely, $f\equiv f(x_0)$ in $\Omega$. Why is that a contradiction to our assumptions?

Comment: But by construction $$\max \{ f(x) : x \in K\} = \max \{ f(x) : x \in \mathbb{R}^n\},$$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a domain.

Comment: Ah, I see where my lack of understanding comes from: In my lecture (and unfortunately in the text book I read too) we use the global assumption "$\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain" and we state all statements with respect to that $\Omega$. Now, I see that we don't need boundedness to prove the *strong maximum principle for subharmonic functions*. We only need the connectedness.